# Java 8 - retry a method until a condition is fulfilled (in intervals)

Tags: java, java-8, hamcrest

I want to create a class that can run a method until a condition about the return value is fulfilled.

It should look something like this

```
methodPoller.poll(pollDurationSec, pollIntervalMillis)
            .method(dog.bark())
            .until(dog -> dog.bark().equals("Woof"))
            .execute();
```

My method poller look somewhat like this () // following GuiSim answer

```
public class MethodPoller {
    Duration pollDurationSec;
    int pollIntervalMillis;


    public MethodPoller() {
    }

    public MethodPoller poll(Duration pollDurationSec, int pollIntervalMillis) {
        this.pollDurationSec = pollDurationSec;
        this.pollIntervalMillis = pollIntervalMillis;
        return this;
    }

    public <T> MethodPoller method(Supplier<T> supplier) {

        return this;
    }

    public <T> MethodPoller until(Predicate<T> predicate) {

        return this;
    }
}
```

But I am having a hard time going opn from here.
How can I implement a retry to a general method until a condition is fulfilled?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, regarding the method itself, you could have a reference to the target object, its reflected Method and the required arguments. You could also encapsulate it in a lambda, but it definitely depends on how that method is passed - explicitly or discovered? what about parameters?

Comment: @rails If the answer I have provided satisfies you, please accept it. Do not hesitate if you have further questions.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, this can easily be done in Java 7 and even cleaner using Java 8.

The parameter to your `method` method should be a `java.util.function.Supplier<T>` and the parameter to your `until` method should be a `java.util.function.Predicate<T>`.

You can then use method references or lambda expressions to create you Poller like so:

```
myMethodPoller.poll(pollDurationInteger, intervalInMillisecond)
          .method(payment::getStatus)
          .until (paymentStatus -> paymentStatus.getValue().equals("COMPLETED"))
          .execute();
```

As a side note, if you're going to use Java 8, I'd recommend using `java.time.Duration` instead of an integer to represent the poll duration and the interval.

I'd also recommend looking into https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying which is a library that you could perhaps use. If not, it could be a good inspiration for your API as it features a nice fluent API.

EDIT:
Following the update to the question, here is a simple implementation. I've left some parts for you to complete as TODOs.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class MethodPoller<T> {

    Duration pollDurationSec;
    int pollIntervalMillis;

    private Supplier<T> pollMethod = null;
    private Predicate<T> pollResultPredicate = null;

    public MethodPoller() {
    }

    public MethodPoller<T> poll(Duration pollDurationSec, int pollIntervalMillis) {
        this.pollDurationSec = pollDurationSec;
        this.pollIntervalMillis = pollIntervalMillis;
        return this;
    }

    public MethodPoller<T> method(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        pollMethod = supplier;
        return this;
    }

    public MethodPoller<T> until(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        pollResultPredicate = predicate;
        return this;
    }

    public T execute()
    {
        // TODO: Validate that poll, method and until have been called.

        T result = null;
        boolean pollSucceeded = false;
        // TODO: Add check on poll duration
        // TODO: Use poll interval
        while (!pollSucceeded) {
            result = pollMethod.get();
            pollSucceeded = pollResultPredicate.test(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Sample use:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MethodPollerTest
{

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        MethodPoller<String> poller = new MethodPoller<>();
        String uuidThatStartsWithOneTwoThree = poller.method(() -> UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                                                     .until(s -> s.startsWith("123"))
                                                     .execute();
        assertTrue(uuidThatStartsWithOneTwoThree.startsWith("123"));
        System.out.println(uuidThatStartsWithOneTwoThree);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There are many gems in your answer. Updated the question because I still need some assistance. thanks.

Comment: May I suggest condensing the `while` loop to `while(!pollResultPredicate.test(pollMethod.get()) Thread.sleep(calculateDuration());`.

Comment: @ndm13 It depends. If you need to obtain the result after it has passed validation, you need to keep a reference.

Comment: `public MethodPoller poll` should be `public MethodPoller<T> poll` to avoid unchecked raw types

Comment: Will this block the thread from processing other requests when its executing?

Comment: @HarshaKA yes. If this is not desired, you can run this in a daemon thread.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of writing this yourself, could you use [Awaitility](https://github.com/jayway/awaitility)?

```
await()
    .atMost(3, SECONDS)
    .until(dog::bark, equalTo("woof"));
```

Comment: Even tho this works real nice `Awaitility` is better suited for testing code, not production

Comment: @Icardito, busy wait isn't a best practice for production but if you already have such, there is no need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

```
  Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                .map(tick -> dog)
                .takeWhile( dog-> { return ! dog.bark().equals("Woof"); })
                .subscribe(dog ->dog.bark());


        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

http://blog.freeside.co/2015/01/29/simple-background-polling-with-rxjava/